# Is there a more concise way to rotate through an array?

Tags: javascript

Basically I have a function that updates a global the next value, if you end up on the last one you start over. This seems like a very complex way of achieving that, but I don't know any better.

```
var state
next () {
    const states = [false, 'zoomIn', 'addBg', 'zoom', 'removeBg', 'zoomOut']
    const i = states.indexOf(this.state.zoom)
    state = typeof states[i + 1] !== 'undefined' ? states[i + 1] : false
}
next()
```

Comment: well you can keep a counter and reset it instead of looking for the index. OR you can use shift/push to move items in an array just select the first one.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Question is looking for optimisations and belongs to [Code Reviews](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @Rajesh thanks for the feedback, I had no idea :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to keep that `state` variable, then replace

```
state = typeof states[i + 1] !== 'undefined' ? states[i + 1] : false
```

with

```
state = states[(i+1)%states.length]
```

[Remainder operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Remainder_())

Otherwise it would be cleaner to just keep the function by using a factory:

```
var next = (function(){
    const states = [false, 'zoomIn', 'addBg', 'zoom', 'removeBg', 'zoomOut'];
    var i = 0;
    return function(){
        return states[(i++)%states.length];
    }
})();
next(); => returns the next state
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can use the mod of `states.length` like this:

```
var state
next() {
  const states = [false,'zoomIn', 'addBg', 'zoom', 'removeBg', 'zoomOut'];
  const i = states.indexOf(this.state.zoom);
  state = states[(i+1)%states.length];
}
next ();
```